# How convert List to DirectoryInfo

Tags: c#, directoryinfo

In my application, I have a specific directory like "C:\Temp\Folder1", imagine this directory has the following sub directories:

```
C:\Temp\Folder1\Admin\Billy
C:\Temp\Folder1\Customer\Michael
C:\Temp\Folder1\Admin\Julian
C:\Temp\Folder1\Customer\May
C:\Temp\Folder1\Admin\Sebastian
```

I use DirectoryInfo.GetDirectories() to get all above sub directories and convert into a list to filter out folders with C:\Temp\Folder1\Admin\ and I'm manage to do that. So only "Customer" folder will be remain in the DirectoryInfo variable.

Imagine my list has the following item only:

```
C:\Temp\Folder1\Customer\Michael
C:\Temp\Folder1\Customer\May
```

But now i have one problem, I need to delete the Customer folders that are available in the DirectoryInfo variable but the filtered records is a list, not a DirectoryInfo class so I couldn't use the DirectoryInfo.Delete() to delete each Customer folder.

So how do I convert the list to DirectoryInfo or manually add each item in the list into DirectoryInfo so that I can perform deletion on each Customer folder?

Comment: Use loop through list and call Directory.Delete() for each item. Take a look this site: https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/fxeahc5f(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how do I convert the list to DirectoryInfo or manually add each item
>   in the list into DirectoryInfo so that I can perform deletion on each
>   Customer folder?

You can project each element using [`Enumerable.Select`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb548891(v=vs.100).aspx) and create a `DirectoryInfo` from each one:

```
foreach (var directory in listOfPaths.Select(path => new DirectoryInfo(path))
{
    directory.Delete();
}
```

Comment: You can also use a listOfPaths.Where(path => path.Contains("Admin")) to filter your results down even further.  Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the guidance. But due to a more complicated requirement, I convert the DirectoryInfo to list using List<DirectoryInfo> and I'm able to use Delete() after filtering. Thanks a lot of your hints

Answer (score 0):

You should check out the System.IO.Directory.Delete(string path) method. This would not require creating a new object just to delete the folder.